# replace-regex to remove first element from camel case function name

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have code like this:

```
<?= $this->Article->getShowComments(); ?>
```

and need to convert it to

```
{{ Article.showComments }}
```

everything is easy with simple regex: exception `.getFooBar` to `.fooBar`, how can I do this in Elisp, is there something like replace using a function like in javascript?

Comment: You could check http://www.emacswiki.org/CamelCase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `case-fold-search` to `nil`:

```
M-x set-variable RET case-fold-search RET nil
```

Now, use the following command for the transformation:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET \_<\(?:[a-z0-9]\|\s_\)+\([A-Z]\) RET \,(downcase \1)
```

The first argument is the regexp to search for, the second is the replacement text.

The regexp is a little complicated, but essentially matches a symbol starting (`\_<` is symbol start) with either lowercase letters or digits (`[a-z0-9]`) or non-word symbol characters (`\s_`), followed by a single uppercase letter `[A-Z]`.  The first non-grouping parenthesis `\(?:…\)` just groups the or-operator `\|`.

The second parenthesis around the uppercase letter is grouping, which creates the “reference” `\1` for use in our replacement text.

We wrap the reference to the matched uppercase letter into the function `downcase` to convert it to lowercase.  The `\,` in the replacement text just tells Emacs, that the following text is a proper sexp to be evaluated and not just a simple string.

**Edit 1)** The `rx` variant of this RE is probably easier to understand:

```
(and symbol-start 
     (one-or-more (or (any "a-z" "0-9") (syntax symbol))) 
     (group-n 1 (any "A-Z"))
```

Unfortunately you can't use RX expressions in `replace-match`.

**Edit 2)** `replace-regexp` is intended for **interactive use only**.  It should not be used non-interactively, i.e. from Emacs Lisp.  Notably, when used non-interactively, this function will not compile the replacement text, so the special `\,` escape will **not work**!

From Emacs Lisp, use `re-search-forward` and `replace-match`:

```
(let ((case-fold-search nil)
      (regexp (rx symbol-start 
                   (one-or-more (or (any "a-z" "0-9") (syntax symbol))) 
                   (group-n 1 (any "A-Z")))))
  (while (re-search-forward regexp nil 'no-error)
    (replace-match (downcase (match-string 1)) 'fixed-case 'literal)))
```

Make sure to wrap this in `with-current-buffer` to make it operate on the right buffer.

Comment: The macro `rx` can be used to convert 'rx-expressions' to raw regular expressions

Comment: `\,` is just what I was looking for, rx is also handy. Why you escape `_` at the begining of the regex?

Comment: @jcubic `\_<` matches the empty string, but only at the start of a symbol.  I use it to avoid matching lowercase letter in the middle of a symbol.  In other words, it makes sure that the regexp only matches `getS`, but not `howC` in your example.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari I know, but you can't do that inplace from `replace-regexp`.

Comment: I've try to execute this: `(replace-regexp "<\\?= \\$this->\\([^\-]+\\)->get\\([A-Z]\\)\\([^(]+\\)();?\s*\\?>" "{{ \\1.\\,(downcase \\2)\\3 }}")` from elisp buffer but got error `replace-match-maybe-edit: Invalid use of '\' in replacement text`.

Comment: @jcubic You can't call this from a Lisp buffer.  There's a reason why I've shown you the *interactive* command, you know…  why don't you just use it?  Anyhow, I've updated my answer with instructions about how to use this from Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got in my attic for this:

```lisp
(defun CamelCase->underscore (str)
  (mapconcat 'identity (CamelCase->list str) "_"))

(defun CamelCase->list (str)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil)
        (pos 0)
        words)
    (while (string-match ".[^A-Z]*" str pos)
      (let ((word (downcase (match-string-no-properties 0 str))))
        (if (> (length word) 1)
            (push word words)
          (setq words (cons (concat (car words) word)
                            (cdr words)))))
      (setq pos (match-end 0)))
    (reverse words)))
(CamelCase->underscore "getShowComments")
;; => "get_show_comments"
```

Just needs a bit of adapting for your case.

And here's the adaptation:

```lisp
(defun CamelCase->something (str)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil)
        (pos 0)
        words)
    (while (string-match ".[^A-Z]*" str pos)
      (let ((word (match-string-no-properties 0 str)))
        (if (> (length word) 1)
            (push word words)
          (setq words (cons (concat (car words) word)
                            (cdr words)))))
      (setq pos (match-end 0)))
    (setq words (cdr (reverse words)))
    (mapconcat 'identity
               (cons (downcase (car words)) (cdr words))
               "")))
```